# Exception code: 0xe0434f4d

Tags: .net

I got the following error while trying to run windows application:
Faulting application name: cribbageDemo.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f685fe3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16850, time stamp: 0x4e211da1
Exception code: 0xe0434f4d

more error information::::

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>100</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-03-20T10:47:40.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>4148</EventRecordID> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>Mayank-PC</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>cribbageDemo.exe</Data> 
<Data>1.0.0.0</Data> 
<Data>4f685fe3</Data> 
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
<Data>6.1.7600.16850</Data> 
<Data>4e211da1</Data> 
<Data>e0434f4d</Data> 
<Data>000000000000a88d</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

When i am running my application application crashes ....not able to get logs also...

Comment: Is this an application you've written?

Comment: This is actually a very good question because this is one of the net framework failures states that makes no sense at all but the error code is in the title so Google finds this one right away.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using a .config file with "supportedRuntime", check if the runtime given is >= the compiling runtime.

I got this error when changing to .Net 4.5 and in this file was an old 2.x entry.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12643167)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Please help me:Why is this not the answer to the question? I got exact the same error codes. Even this post is four years old, I did not find anything on web. This happens often, if the .Net loader could not load the assembly. And my answer was one the possible reasons which is easily overseen. With this I want so archive my experience for other searchers...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering... What you have written should be a comment, IMO, since you're asking info to the OP.

Comment: This *does* at least try to answer the question, it was just worded badly.

Comment: I had a similar error and in my case the problem was a lack of an app.config file. Once that was added to the project the problem went away.

Comment: This answer worked for me.Thanks @RalphErdt ! =)

Comment: This is a good answer.  The 'duplicate' marked answer seems too vaguely related to be considered a duplicate.  The answer addresses the specific problem in the question.

Comment: This answer worked for me too.  Someone left an old .config file indicating 2.0 which caused the error. Thanks @RalphErdt.